# Orden de caracteres en Free Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

En Pascal los tipo `char` están ordenados, y no se cuál es ese orden. Por ejemplo, si tengo el dígito `5` y quiero hacer que tome el valor del entero `5` hago `ord('5')`? ¿Pero tiene ese valor o es otro ? ¿Alguien tiene la lista de los carácteres en orden?

Answer (score 1):

Los caracteres no están ordenados porque sea PASCAL. Existen unas tablas que convierten una codificación numérica en caracteres (de ahí viene UTF-8, ANSI, ...).

La más básica es la tabla ASCII, que puedes consultar por ejemplo [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). En ella aparecen los caracteres básicos para el idioma inglés. Si echas un vistazo a la tabla, verás que al carácter `'5'` le corresponde el valor 0x35 en hexadecimal y al `'6'` le corresponde el valor 0x36. Esto explica que si le sumas uno al caracter parece que estás incrementando el valor del número.

Con esto en mente, y echando un vistazo a la tabla, parece obvio que hacer:

```
char c := '1';
c := c + 1;
```

va a dar como resultado `c='2'`.

Sin embargo, este sistema no debería usarse para realizar operaciones matemáticas ya que hacer:

```
char c := '9';
c := c + 1;
```

No va a dar como resultado `'10'`, y ya ni hablemos de las multiplicaciones.

Si vas a trabajar con valores numéricos, haz una conversión de `'5'` a `5` y trabaja con números en vez de con caracteres. Una pista: para obtener el número al que corresponde un carácter numérico basta con restar `0x30`

Comment: Muchas gracias! si supuse que me conviene mas trabajar con numeros que con tipo char, mi duda surgio de un ejercicio en el que utiliza una cadena de char, y despues quiere hacer calculos con sus valores. Gracias por tu respuesta, ha sido de mucha ayuda

Comment: @Pascal101 si la respuesta soluciona tu duda no olvides marcarla como solución para que los que vengan detrás de ti sepan qué respuesta se ajusta mejor a tu pregunta

Comment: Esta respuesta es muy buena, pero utiliza conceptos y ejemplos del lenguaje c. En pascal, no puedes declarar una variable de tipo char y luego sumarle un número, eso daría lugar a un error de compilación. Sin embargo, la idea subyacente es la misma.

Answer (score 0):

Es el código ASCII, tienes aquí una tabla:

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! ha sido de mucha ayuda

Comment: No es por ASCII, es por UTF-8. Sucede que UTF-8 y ASCII coinciden en los primeros caracteres.

Comment: Pues en la propia documentación dicen que siguen el estándar ASCII http://wiki.freepascal.org/Char/es